# open cv and c++ object detection real time

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

hi i use a open cv for detect object and without problem >>

but the problem when i move the camera every think is detected because i detect without color with real time how can i recognize if the object moving or the camera i thinking about this and found some idea its

.........

first add point on center of image (the image come from video)

and when i check for moving object if its distance didnt change so its didnt move and the moving its from camera  did my idea good and how to add object to or poit to image

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to tell whether the object is moving or the camera. When there is only one camera, the solutions are usually using a reference (not-moving) object or use a mechanic sensor for camera movement. If you use two camera, you can usually calibrate them and use stereo vision formulations to solve the problem.